# Other options than NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted?

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

I convert a `NSDictionary` to JSON `NSData` with the following line:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:answers 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&err];
```

And pass it to server side, which is a PHP script. The script reads the JSON string as:

```
{
  "A" : "1941",
  "D" : "1699",
  "B" : "1949",
  "E" : "1823",
  "C" : "1999"
}
```

How can I format the JSON string as 1 line, just like below?

```
{"A" : "1941", "D" : "1699", "B" : "1949", "E" : "1823", "C" : "1999"}
```

Is there any option other than `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` ?

Comment: Just don't specify that option.  `options:` can be zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation for `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSJSONWritingOptions);

> If this option is not set, the most compact possible JSON representation is generated.

If you don't want to set any bits in the writing options mask, just pass zero for that parameter. (Or in Swift, an empty option-set, which looks just like an empty array: `[]`.)

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` for purposes other than debugging. You can pass in `options:0` (see below) to have the minified JSON.

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:answers options:0 error:&err];
```

To verify this, you can convert it into a string and `NSLog` it.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

There are no other options other than `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSJSONWritingOptions) {
    NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted = (1UL << 0)
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0);
```